# pandas read_excel throws ValueError: Value does not match pattern

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I want to read an excel file as pandas Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path = r"my/path/to/file"
file = "myFile.xlsx"

df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(path, file))
```

and receive following error:

> ValueError: Value does not match pattern
> ^[$]?([A-Za-z]{1,3})[$]?(\d+)(:[$]?([A-Za-z]{1,3})[$]?(\d+)?)?$|^[A-Za-z]{1,3}:[A-Za-z]{1,3}$

The excel file has per default an active filter. If I perform a workaround using the `xlwings` library I can read the excel file as a Dataframe afterwards:

```
#Start Workaround
wb = xw.Book(os.path.join(path, file))

if wb.sheets["Sheet1"].api.AutoFilterMode == True:
      wb.sheets["Sheet1"].api.AutoFilterMode = False

wb.save()
wb.close()
#End Workaround

df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(path, file)) #works now
```

Since a security update I need to confirm manually a Dialog Box after opening the file with `xlwings`. Does anyone know how one can read the excel directly into a Dataframe without using the workaround?

FYI I can't  replicate the error with another excel file where I save it with an active filter...

Comment: Are you sure that the filter is the problem? If you remove the filter and save it as a different file, can pandas read that file?
In my experience, this is more often caused by a protected range, complex formulas or conditional formatting.

Comment: Could be that it is not the filter itself. but opening and saving the file with xlwings seems to overwrite some settings that pandas can't handle.

Comment: btw its not a pandas error as such, it comes from Openpyxl which pandas is using to open the file.